# WKWebView reload() can't refresh current page

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

the first time load web page fail at offline.
then I connect network call `reload()` to refresh current page, but it is not work, the `WKNavigationDelegate` can't get any callback.

the function `reloadFromOrigin()` also not work

but the doc says:

```
/*! @abstract Reloads the current page.
 @result A new navigation representing the reload.
 */
- (nullable WKNavigation *)reload;

/*! @abstract Reloads the current page, performing end-to-end revalidation
 using cache-validating conditionals if possible.
 @result A new navigation representing the reload.
 */
- (nullable WKNavigation *)reloadFromOrigin;
```

Can someone help

Comment: If the first URL WKWebView tries to load fails, the active URL will be nil. On every reload call it will be trying to load nil. You can check the URL parameter of the webview before reloading.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first time load web page fail at offline. Then webview.url be `nil`. Try the following code:

```
func reloadButtonDidTap() {
    if webview.url != nil {
        webview.reload()
    } else {
        webview.load(URLRequest(url: originalURL))
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid a Swift warning about unused url variable, fix the "if" line to:  if let _ = webview.url {