# Restart ios app after Ipad Locks/Shuts off

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, web, ipad

I've searched for hours on this so perhaps I am searching for the wrong terminology. but I have an ios web app that I created and I'm just wondering if there is anyway to force the app to restart/reload any time that the Ipad locks or is shut off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> force the app to restart

no, you can't do that, it's not allowed, alternative you can exit your app(also not allowed)

> reload any time that the Ipad locks or is shut off?

since you are developing a web app, you can reload the web page(not the whole app) by `webView.reload()`, if the webView doesn't refresh,  [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45706866/6458679).

when the device is locked, `func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` will be called, notice, not only locked, but also background, phone call or sms message and so on. so if you only care about the 'Lock' event, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/706344/6458679)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this! This is exactly what I need. How do i trigger 'webView.reload()' when the ipad gets unlocked

Comment: @Westonleavitt ` func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)`