# WKWebView app unloads in background - reliable way to check

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

sometimes in background my WKWebView app unloads - when I open it I have only WKWebView background and the app doesn't respond. I managed to catch it once - I debugged it in safari dev tools and found out at that time it had 'about:blank' url loaded instead of my app url. So I did the following:

```
    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        generateHapticFeedback(feedbackId: 4)
        
        let isAlive: Bool = webView.url?.absoluteString != URL(string:"about:blank")?.absoluteString
        
        if (isAlive) {
            print("[alive_check] OK, NO RELOAD NEEDED")
            return
        } else {
            print("[alive_check] HANGED")
            configurateWebView()
            HTMLLoader.loadScenario(for: webView)
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("alert('DEV MODE: APP HANG DETECTED. REINIT TO THE RESQUE ‍♀️')")
        }
    }
```

I verified my approach works fine for scenario with 'about:blank' - to test it I just set `window.location.href = 'about:blank'` manually via safari dev tools. But it seems that app doesn't always have this state when unloads (this morning I have this again, and the fix doesn't help. at the same time I'm unable to connect to it with debugger after the night)

Do I have any reliable way to check that my page is still running in WKWebView and if no I will force it to reload?

I also tried to [evaluate javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68434118/1665293) to communicate to my page but it doesn't return anything.

Solutions I don't want to consider as of now:

- [Keep it live in background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40739474/1665293) - reloading the page is completely fine to me as the app will restore it's state.
- Reinitialize it every time on `applicationDidBecomeActive` as it looks a bit ugly in terms of UX.

Comment: what I'm doing now: I've added javascript `alert` to show the `url` and `isAlive` on screen every time so I will be able to see at least what is the location when it hangs next time - I believe the app still works as `generateHapticFeedback()` triggerrs fine in the `applicationDidBecomeActive`. but this will take time to reproduce and I'm not sure if Im going in a good direction

Comment: thinking out loud: probably at that `unloaded` state I might have `nil` in url as per first comment here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706866/wkwebview-reload-cant-refresh-current-page

Comment: yep it was `nil`, described solution in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the following - iOS unloads app into two different states:

1. `webView.url?.absoluteString == nil`
2. `webView.url?.absoluteString == "about:blank"`

This states usually appear as white `webView` screen, mine has the color of the app though so it doesn't flash on loading)

so what I did - on app activation I check that `webView` url contains my `MY_URL_NAME_SEGMENT` and  url is not `nil`. This covers both cases I have when my app is unloaded. See the code below:

```swift
    @objc func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        let currentUrl = webView.url?.absoluteString
        let isAlive = currentUrl != nil && currentUrl!.localizedLowercase.contains("MY_URL_NAME_SEGMENT".localizedLowercase)

        if (isAlive) {
            print("[alive_check] OK, NO RELOAD NEEDED")
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("alert('[✅ OK] isAlive: \(isAlive). URL: \(String(describing: webView.url?.absoluteString))')")
        } else {
            print("[alive_check] HANGED")
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("alert('[❌ RELOADED] isAlive: \(isAlive). URL: \(String(describing: webView.url?.absoluteString))')")
            configurateWebView()
            HTMLLoader.loadScenario(for: webView)//inside I just load html
        }
        
    }
```

I also left example how I call javascript `alert()` so you will be able to debug the values anytime (you won't need to connect to debugger). Just make sure JS alerts works in your app in general - they must be implemented in your extension.